# How to do you make both a Razor Page and C# code framework with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, frameworks, nuget-package

I have written a rather simple ASP.NET Core web app, which I would like to use as a framework for my future web apps.

- How can I get both functionalities in one single NuGet package - that is the C# and the razor pages templates for future projects?
- How do I make this kind of template? I can't seem to find any tutorials for the whole package.
- How do I specify a settings or similar logic for fitting in some variables like the general page name?

Comment: Create your razor project, add views etc... add your extra c# classes/helpers/whatever...
Done
There is no secret to this.
(what am I missing?)

Comment: @AndyPook then it's not a real framework?.. I made a project with two libraries - one with C# code only and the other one with Razor pages only and I'm experimenting whether this works.. So far I have no clue how to do the third point (newly added to the question)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I specify a settings or similar logic for fitting in some variables like the general page name?

As far as I know, we could modify the asp.net core routes to modify the each routes.

For example, the controller is homecontroller and then you use set the attribute route to modify it like "test" like this ``.

If you want to make this web application's pages has a specific pre-fix, you could set it as Area.

```
[Route("Blog/{action}")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Comment: This just opens up an endpoint?.. I don't quite see how this would help me..